# How does Google Gmail store their "email" messages?

Tags: gmail, storage

How does Google store their 7GB/user emails such that it is blazing fast for retrieval and also not subject to corruption.

Is it in those NoSQL database or just jornaling file system ?

Comment: In this page there are links some of the various technologies Google uses. http://highscalability.com/google-architecture

Answer (score 3):

According to the paper ["The Learning Behind Gmail Priority Inbox"](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36955.pdf), Google makes "extensive use of bigtable, which combines features of a distributed ﬁle system with a database."

BigTable has been described in a [2006 OSDI paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/labs.google.com/en//papers/bigtable-osdi06.pdf).